# How to prevent Google Places from returning addresses in Arabic?

Tags: javascript, location, google-places-api, arabic, google-places

I've been using the Google Places JavaScript SDK for some time, supporting address lookups in both Australia and the UAE. Recently, UAE addresses are coming back with certain address components displayed in Arabic.

We are passing language and region parameters to our script source to specify english, but this doesn't really help: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&libraries=places&language=en-au&region=au. Interestingly, changing the language to Japanese does seem to get most address components back in latin letters, but not all.

Has anyone else noticed this and have any idea on how to resolve it?